# Extract substring from row in SQL table and convert to date

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to extract one row of data from a SQL Server table via PowerShell and convert the extracted value into a date.

The first 8 chars of the string should be in `yyyymmdd` format.

Firstly, I am having problems extracting the row...

As per various posts I've seen, it appears that when you grab a row, the data type that is returned is `System.Data.DataRow`. You then need to convert it into an `Array`. How do I grab the values from the array/datarow? Ideally, I'd like the value to come back as a `String` - as there will only be one value returned.
I am currently using something like this - but the content is `null` (even though the statement in SSMS returns one row)...

`[array]$lastSQLdateArray = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance INSTANCE -Database DATABASE -Query "SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(Column, 8) FROM [dbo].[Table] ORDER BY ID DESC"`

```
for ($i=0; $i -le $lastSQLdateArray.Length; $i++)
{
  $formatOut = $formatOut + ($lastSQLdateArray[$i].ItemArray -join ",")
}
```

Then there is the question of converting the extracted `yyyymmdd` value (which ever data type it is) and convert it to a `date`.

How can I do this please?

Comment: First question, why are you storing dates as string in the first place? Seems that you would help yourself considerably by fixing the datatype of the original table. The right datatype is crucial in designing a database. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: @SeanLange Very good point.  My answer below will work to convert the data, but it is significantly better to never have to convert in the first place.

Comment: Hi. These are filenames I am dealing with, not dates per say. I have date columns already in the table which bear no relevance to these filenames.

Comment: You could add a computed column that is a date, then you would have the date part of the filename separated.

Comment: @SeanLange Fair point - but i'd rather find a solution for this is as is. Besides, i'm sure this will not be the only time I encounter this so a solution to this would be beneficial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, warnerj79. First of all, your SQL statement is a bit ambiguous.  I would recommend always specifying `AS ColumnName` when calculating parameters.  It will help later on.  I also like to put my SQL in a variable for readability.
So your SQL line becomes:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(Column, 8) AS 'DateTimeString' FROM [dbo].[Table] ORDER BY ID DESC"
[array]$lastSQLdateArray = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance INSTANCE -Database DATABASE -Query $strSQL
```

Then, your results variable (`[array]$lastSQLdateArray`) will contain one row (due to your use of `TOP 1`, so you would access the `YYYYMMDD` property like this:

```
$lastSQLdateArray[0].DateTimeString
```

Or because it is only one element in the array, this will work also:

```
$lastSQLdateArray.DateTimeString
```

That value is in a string format.  In order to convert that to a `[datetime]` variable, I would use the `parseexact` method like so:

```
$DateTimeVariable = [datetime]::ParseExact($lastSQLdateArray[0].DateTimeString,'yyyyMMdd',$null)
```

EDIT: Added the following test data:

I created a test table in my SQL server called "m_test1" with the following data:

> ID      Column
>
> 1       20200218junk

I used these statements:

```
$strSQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 LEFT([Column],8) as COL FROM [TEST].[dbo].[m_test1] ORDER BY ID'
$lastSQLDateArray = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'servername' -Database 'TEST' -Query $strSQL
```

And I got the following:

```
PS C:> $returnvalue
 
COL     
---
20200218
 
PS C:> $returnvalue.COL
20200218

PS C:> [datetime]::ParseExact($returnvalue.COL,'yyyyMMdd',$null)

Tuesday, February 18, 2020 12:00:00 AM
```

Hope this helps!  If it does, please don't forget to accept the answer using the check mark to the left.

Comment: Hi Matthew. Thanks for your swift reply! The DateTimeString method brought back a null value - whereas not using the method brought back the column and value..... (as expected). Is this the correct method or is something not quite right...?

Comment: See my edits above adding test values.  I'm not sure what it is you are doing, but my testing shows my solution to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance.
With your help, I have managed to sort the issue using the following syntax:

```
$strSQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(Colname, 8) AS Col FROM [dbo].[Table] ORDER BY ID DESC'

$lastSQLdateArray1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'server' -Database 'database' -Query $strSQL

$newvar = [datetime]::ParseExact($lastSQLdateArray1.Col.ToString(),'yyyyMMdd',$null)

$newvar
```

Only main difference is that I placed .ToString() in the date conversion line.

Thanks once again for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help, and happy to see you figured it out!